Why do the hydrogen-based jet engines create propulsion?
Theoretically, the jet engines create propulsion because of the pressure in the combustion chamber that creates force that pushes the rocket.
But when hydrogen combustion is conducted, 2 hydrogen molecules and 1 oxygen molecule create 2 water molecules, that is instead of 3 molecules obtained 2. This means, the pressure reduces to 2/3 of the original pressure.
The heating of the water vapor cannot compensate for this: try to put a burning match into a bottle, the pressure there will reduce despite the air being heated.
So, how a hydrogen-oxygen engine can create propulsion if the burning reduces the pressure in the combustion chamber? Would not it be even more effective to just allow the gases to go out without burning them?


The heating of the water vapor cannot compensate for this

But it can, and it does.
The constant-pressure adiabatic flame temperature approximates the temperature resulting from a flame in an open container. (Higher temperatures will be achieved in a constant-volume process.) Many values can be found in the literature, but for stoichiometric hydrogen in air, most sources give a value around 2500 K (one arbitrarily selected example: [1]). This paper assumed the fuel and air had an input temperature of 298 K. So the temperature increased by a factor of 2500/298 = 8.4.
What about the number of molecules? Air is about 20% oxygen, so this stoichiometric combustion involved 2 moles of hydrogen for every 5 moles of air (consisting of 4 moles of nitrogen and 1 mole of oxygen). The combustion ends with the same 4 moles of nitrogen, no oxygen or hydrogen, and 2 moles of water. So the number of moles of gas has decreased from 7 to 6, a factor of 0.86.
The ideal gas law $PV \propto nT$ says that under constant pressure conditions, a change in $nT$ by a factor of $8.4 \times 0.86 = 7.2$ results in an increase in the volume by the same factor of 7.2. A volume increase by a factor of 7.2 is certainly enough to power a jet engine. There is actually a lot of room to spare, which is good, because we probably won't actually achieve the adiabatic flame temperature.
The match-in-bottle demonstration typically gives the opposite result for at least two reasons, both of which boil down to it being a very bad model of a jet engine.
First, jet engines vent the exhaust gas at a high temperature. The gas is not allowed to lose much heat until it has already left the engine. By contrast, the match-in-bottle retains the exhaust gas, allowing it to condense on the cold walls of the bottle. The exhaust soon extinguishes the flame, upon which the gas cools and contracts even further. If you allow the exhaust gas to condense inside a jet engine, you will likely get similarly poor results. This problem could be solved by preheating the bottle. (A real jet engine will heat itself up pretty quickly during the starting process, but the match flame is too small and the fuel and oxygen are too limited.)
Second, at least some of the gas inside the bottle is generally allowed to heat up before the bottle is sealed. The bottle is thus sealed in an already-expanded condition, and most of the expansion of the gases is not measured. If you were to light the match after it was sealed inside the bottle (say, with an electric spark) you would have a better chance to measure the initial expansion before the eventual flameout and contraction.
[1] Marzouk, "Adiabatic Flame Temperatures for Oxy-Methane, Oxy-Hydrogen, Air-Methane, and Air-Hydrogen Stoichiometric Combustion using the NASA CEARUN Tool, GRI-Mech 3.0 Reaction Mechanism, and Cantera Python Package
," 2023 (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4547389).

Excellent exposition! -NN

There is no air in rocket engine, there is only oxygen and hydrogen. You should compare combusted gases to non-combusted ones. Obviously, the non-combusted have greater volume or pressure.

@Anixx A jet engine and a rocket engine are quite different, and I did give you the answer for the jet engine, but you can easily do the calculation for pure hydrogen/oxygen combustion using the method I've described. (There is even a hydrogen/oxygen flame temperature in the same paper I linked.) I would highly recommend that you do the calculation; you'll find out that what you claim is "obvious" is in fact not true. If you are still confused after performing the calculation, please share you work and maybe we can offer some help.

As far as I know, rockets use jet engines.

An airplane with a jet engine uses air from outside to burn its fuel, which is typically kerosene. A rocket typically uses liquid hydrogen and liquid oxygen, though other things are sometimes used. For lots of information about rocket engines, see the Rocket Deep Dives videos at Everyday Astronaut
